# Remove %20 from url routing in visual studio 2008 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, url-routing, urldecode

how to remove "%20" from url?

http://myweb.com/India%20is%20a%20great%20country

i want like below url.....

http://myweb.com/India-is-a-great-country

below is my code: for url routing.

```
public class PostRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        string sub = requestContext.RouteData.Values["sub"] as string;


        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sub))
            return Helpers.GetNotFoundHttpHandler();
        else
        {

            if (sub == null)
                return Helpers.GetNotFoundHttpHandler();
            else
            {


                HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(sub);
                return BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath("~/ViewEntry.aspx",  typeof(Page)) as Page;
            }
        }
    }
}


public class Helpers
{

    public static string FormatProductUrl(string sub)
    {
        return RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(null, "View Product", new RouteValueDictionary { { "sub", sub } }).VirtualPath;
}


    public static IHttpHandler GetNotFoundHttpHandler()
    {
        return BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath("~/NotFound.aspx", typeof(Page)) as Page;
    }
}



<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>

<script runat="server">

void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{

    string pathAndQuery = Request.Url.PathAndQuery.ToString().ToLower();

    // Register a route for Products/{ProductName}
    routes.Add(
        "View Product",
        new Route("{sub}", new WebApplication1.PostRouteHandler())
    );

}
```

and below is the link:

```
 <h3 style=" padding-bottom:7px"> <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkProduct"
                NavigateUrl='<%# Helpers.FormatProductUrl(Eval("sub").ToString()) %>' Text='<%# Eval("sub") %>'>
                </asp:HyperLink>     </h3>
```

i am using 3.5 version visual studio 2008...

Comment: you can replace "%20" with "-"

Answer (score 0):

Use `HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(sub);`  for the same.

Comment: it is not working where to use below code ..

 HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(sub);

Comment: replace your HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(sub); with HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(sub); and try